# How to create array accessible by X and Y coordinates?

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing PHP script, which will store mouse position over the page with a timestamp. It will be used for generating simple heatmap.
I have MySQL database of X & Y coordinates and I thought, that I would do an array, which I would use for adding counts of appearances of the cursor over specific pixel.
It would work like this:
I read data from the database saying for example four recordings (x/y) 10/9,8/7,2/10,10/9
I would put 1 on each of the coordinates in the array, the last point would already in the array, so it would put 2 on x=10/y=9, as total count of mouse being over that pixel.

How should I make the array and how to read it?

Comment: it seems you have an idea of what you want, but what have you tried? the pattern of the array seems to be ready for writing

Comment: @geoPhoenix my problem is, that I am very bad with arrays. I've tried this approach:

$arr = array( array(2, 10 , 9),
               array(1, 8 , 7),
               array(1, 2 , 10) 
             );
But how to check the value of specific X and Y + how to change the value for coordinates afterwards. 
As I wrote, I am absolute noob when it comes to arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create an empty matrix, where the entire grid is defined and populated with zeros:

```
$width = 10;
$height = 10;

$matrix = array_fill(1, $height, array_fill(1, $width, 0));
```

Now you simply iterate over your MySQL results and increment each associated point every time you hit it. In this example I assume your x and y columns are just called `x` and `y`.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {
  $matrix[$row['y']][$row['x']]++;
}
```

Now if you want to get the number of hits for the point where e.g. `x = 1, y = 8`, you simply do:

```
$hits = $matrix[8][1];
```

You can swap the levels round so `x` is on the outer level so they can be referenced as `$matrix[$x][$y]` instead of `$matrix[$y][$x]` if you wish, but I personally feel it makes more sense if the array is structured as rows of columns (`y`s of `x`s) like a database table.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: No worries. Not that it really makes enough of a difference to matter, but I have just realised that a nested `array_fill()` can be used to populate both levels of the initial `$matrix` *slightly* more efficiently without the loop, I have edited my example accordingly.